# How do I get oauth_timestamp, oauth_nonce, oauth_signature for Flickr OAuth on android

Tags: javascript, php, android, oauth, flickr

For Flickr OAuth authentication, I'm authenticating the user I'm already getting OAuth token.

```
OAuth mOauth = OAuth.newInstance(activity.getApplicationContext(),
                activity.getSupportFragmentManager(),
                new ClientParametersAuthentication(FlickrDemoConstants.FLICKR_API_KEY,
                        FlickrDemoConstants.FLICKR_API_SECRET),
                AUTHORIZATION_VERIFIER_SERVER_URL,
                TOKEN_SERVER_URL,
                REDIRECT_URL,
                Lists.<String>newArrayList(),
                TEMPORARY_TOKEN_REQUEST_URL);

Credential mCredential = mOauth.authorize10a(
                    userId).getResult();
            if(FlickrDemoConstants.DEBUG_ENABLE) {
                Log.i(TAG, "token: " + mCredential.getAccessToken());
```

But from how do I oauth_timestamp, oauth_nonce, oauth_signature ?